# How can an app tell if it's running on a hackintosh?

Tags: macos

I'd actually just like to know the number of mouse buttons a laptop has (Apple: 1, Hackintosh: 2), but I'm guessing the answer to this would be interchangeable with the answer to the more general question above.

Edited to clarify about counting built-in mouse buttons:
I'm aware you can use an external two-button mouse or control-click, but I'm specifically interested in the number of built-in hardware buttons: The app uses the laptop's onboard button(s) for paging up/down on a window that can change its rotation (which changes the scroll direction of the left/right buttons), and it's a better user experience if the app knows whether there are actually two side-by-side buttons or just a single control surface.

Comment: You shouldn't be asking if a computer is a Hackintosh to figure out how many mouse buttons it has. You can use a multi-button mouse with a regular Mac just fine.

Comment: Macs have 2+ logical mouse buttons just like PCs.  The MacBook's trackpad is fully capable of right-click type functionality through multitouch.

Comment: I certainly don't know the answer to this, but I just can't imagine there is an answer to this. Especially considering how much change has occurred with mac trackpads over just the past couple of years.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could compare the files that Hackintosh patches with a vanilla installation of Mac OS X. I'm not very knowledgeable about OSX86 though, so I'm not sure exactly how to go about that.

Besides, say for example, you know that the computer is running hackintosh, then what? You'll have to find out that mouse the computer uses, what keyboard, key layout, hardware buttons etc. 
For example, a Dell running Hackintosh will not be the same as a Acer runing Hackintosh.

Why not just skip the middle man and look for the features that you are interested in?

Comment: If you are using Clover bootloader (as every modern hackintosh using this method these days) with on the fly patches, then all kexts under System/Library/Extension and Library/Extension will be vanilla. You cannot tell the difference between the Hackintosh and a Mac this way.